# Decrypt gpg files non-interactively inside a Docker container

Tags: docker, encryption, gnupg

I am trying to decrypt a `gpg` file inside a docker container. Roughly speaking the `Dockerfile` does basic stuff:

```
FROM myimage
RUN ...
...
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /entrypoint
RUN chmod u+x /entrypoint
```

The `docker-entrypoint.sh` contains:

```
gpg --decrypt --passphrase=${PASSWORD} /path/to/encrypted/file > /path/to/unencrypted/file
...
exec "$@"
```

I'm doing:

```
docker build -t "myimage" .
docker run -e PASSWORD -ti myimage
```

And I am getting:

```
gpg: directory `/root/.gnupg' created
gpg: new configuration file `/root/.gnupg/gpg.conf' created
gpg: WARNING: options in `/root/.gnupg/gpg.conf' are not yet active during this run
gpg: keyring `/root/.gnupg/secring.gpg' created               
gpg: keyring `/root/.gnupg/pubring.gpg' created      
usage: gpg [options] --decrypt [filename]
```

…as an error. The password environment var is being passed correctly, and that same command runs correctly on my machine.

I have tried with `gpg2` with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just discovered the issue:

```
gpg --decrypt --passphrase="${PASSWORD}" \
    /path/to/encrypted/file > /path/to/unencrypted/file
```

i.e. quotes should be used in order to the environment variable to be properly transformed to text.

Comment: This is a `bash`  “string interpolation” problem not a gpg problem.